# The Number of Presidencies in the USA

Tags: united-states, president, constitution

May a president in the USA who served two periods come back after a waiting period and be reelected for more times in pattern much as in Russia?

Comment: No.  See the 22nd amendment to the US Constitution: https://constitutioncenter.org/interactive-constitution/amendments/amendment-xxii

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11805/three-term-us-presidential-loophole

Comment: Not a duplicate of _that_ question, that's about another scenario (VP succeeds President after the latter's death)

Comment: @MSalters: the quoted bit of the 22nd Amendment from the answer to the other question covers this (simpler) scenario as well.

Comment: Traditionally, the President of the United States in honor of Washington before FDR served Two Terms.  One president, Grover Cleaveland,  served two non-consecutive terms.   FDR secured four and died in office.  Amendment 22 went into effect during Truman (FDR's successor) and allowed Truman exemption, but Truman was voted out after 2 terms.   Currently the Vice President may serve 3 terms if and only if he suceeds a president who died in office with 2 years or more of his term served.  Under current law, a President may serve at most 10 years minus one day in this manor. 8 years is typical.